# Left outer join two tables through lookup table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two tables

```
Person: { PersonId, Name }
Position: { PositionId, PositionName }
```

They are linked together through a lookup table `[PersonPosition] { PersonId, PositionId }`

The idea is one person can have 0 or more position.

How can I write entity query in C# to left outer join Person with Position through the [PersonPosition] lookup, and produce result like this:

```
[
{
   PersonId: "100": 
   Position: ["Dev, QA"] 
},
{
   PersonId: "200";
   Position: ["Dev"]; 
},
{
   PersonId: "300";
   Position: null; 
},
]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Wouldn't you want that last one to be `Position: [];`?  If you have navigation properties setup it should just be `db.Persons.Include(p => p.Positions);`

Comment: Learn to use navigation properties in LINQ to Entities queries and forget about SQL-ish things like joins (inner, left, outer etc.). Express your intent using objects and collections, and EF will produce the necessary SQL translation - in most of the cases. And this (as well as your previous question) is just one of them - producing the desired result is trivial `Select` once you have `person` with collection of `PersonPosition` or even just `Position` in case it is mapped with EFC 5.0 many-to-many implicit join entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 2 LINQ queries (still might be not an optimal solution)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AppTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var persons = new Person[]
            {
                new Person { Id = 100, Name = "Alpha"},
                new Person { Id = 200, Name = "Beta"},
                new Person { Id = 300, Name = "Gamma"}
            };

            var positions = new Position[]
            {
                new Position { Id = 1, Name = "Dev"},
                new Position { Id = 2, Name = "QA"},
                new Position { Id = 3, Name = "BA"}
            };

            var personPositions = new PersonPosition[]
            {
                new PersonPosition { PersonId=100, PositionId =1},
                new PersonPosition { PersonId=100, PositionId =2},
                new PersonPosition { PersonId=200, PositionId =2},
            };

            var positionsJoin = from position in positions
                                join personPositiontion in personPositions on position.Id equals personPositiontion.PositionId
                                select new
                                {
                                    personPositiontion.PersonId,
                                    position.Name
                                };

            var result = from person in persons
                         join personPositiontion in positionsJoin on person.Id equals personPositiontion.PersonId into jointTable
                         from joint in jointTable.DefaultIfEmpty()                        
                         select new
                         {
                             person.Id,
                             person.Name,
                             PositionName = joint?.Name
                         };

            foreach (var line in result.ToArray())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"id:{line.Id}, name:{line.Name}, position:{line.PositionName}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonPosition
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int PositionId { get; set; }
    }
}
```